# What's the best way of laying this out? Horizontal Rule?

Tags: html, css, layout, rule

I am trying to align a horizontal rule with the white line in my menu. And I want that alignment to stay when viewed on different screens. What's my best option for doing that?  Image of what it needs to look like:

[image: Screenshot]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: jaapokkisubtract;
  src: url('jaapokkisubtract.ttf');
}
body {
  background-color: #ca3600;
}
#head {
  height: 65px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
  float: right;
  width: 51%;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  font-family: jaapokkisubtract;
  font-size: 50px;
  float: left;
}
#work_btn {
  display: block;
  width: 96px;
  height: 68px;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/7m1Eh9j.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  float: right;
}
#work_btn:hover {
  background-position: 0 -68px;
}
#resume_btn {
  display: block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 68px;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/x2eaW4T.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  float: right
}
#resume_btn:hover {
  background-position: 0 -68px;
}
```

```html
 <h1>Alexander</h1>
<div id="menu">
  <a id="resume_btn" href="resume.html" title="Resume">Resume</a>
  <a id="work_btn" href="index.html" title="Work">Work</a>
  <div id="head"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: sorry, added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by modifying slightly the CSS and HTML code, and using translation to move the menu items to the center of the screen.

To do this you need to:

- Wrap everything in div with the border-bottom (e.g.: `#head`)
- Float the page title (`h1`) to the left (although maybe it would be better to change its position to `absolute` or it may affect the menu links)
- Wrap all the navigation elements in a div (e.g.: `#menu`) with absolute position positioned in the center of the `#head` (`left:50%`)
- Transform the `#menu` div to translate it 50% of its width to the left. This could be achieved by adding this to its style:

  ```
  transform:translate(-50%, 0%)
  ```

You can see a demo working here: http://jsfiddle.net/o4ff4thc/ or below:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: jaapokkisubtract;
    src: url('jaapokkisubtract.ttf');
}
body {
    background-color: #ca3600;
}
#head {
    height: 65px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;
}
h1 {
    color: white;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    font-family: jaapokkisubtract;
    font-size: 50px;
    float: left;
}
#work_btn {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 96px;
    height: 68px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/7m1Eh9j.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
#work_btn:hover {
    background-position: 0 -68px;
}
#resume_btn {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 68px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/x2eaW4T.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
#resume_btn:hover {
    background-position: 0 -68px;
}

#menu {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,0%);
    height:20px;
    width:245px;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">
     <h1>Alexander</h1>

    <div id="menu"> 
        <a id="resume_btn" href="resume.html" title="Resume">Resume</a>
        <a id="work_btn" href="index.html" title="Work">Work</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice! Thank you. I wanted the menu in the far right edge so I just changed the % values to 100 and works perfectly.

Comment: If you want the menu in the far right, then it would be better to set `right:0px` and remove the `transform:translate(-50%,0%)` (then it would work in older versions of IE too)